# Change Apache port number using a Bash script on linux

Tags: bash, shell

Im running a web server on my RaspPi and I want to be able to change the http port number Apache uses from a Bash script.

The new port number is coming from a text file containing a bunch of other settings I also use.

It formatted like this
server_port="8080"

I know where it needs to be changed (in 2 places within the Apache install dir) but I am struggling to do it automatically with a bash file as im quite new to Bash scripting.

[This link shows where the new port number is to be entered in the Apache config files](http://www.noveldevices.co.uk/rp-webserverport)

An example of how its done with a great explanation of how it works would be fantastic.

Comment: `in 2 places within the Apache install dir`, what two places. Only needs to be changed in one on mine, but could be far more than two depending how you have it set up.

Comment: According to this link >> http://www.noveldevices.co.uk/rp-webserverport   you need to set the new port in /etc/apache2/ports.conf & /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do a similar thing, except my files are a bit different.  You can look at this script and update/add in the additional file location(s).

Hope this helps:

```
#!/bin/bash
confFile=app.conf
#httpd_conf_file=/etc/apache2/ports.conf. #pi - debian
httpd_conf=/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
newport=8080
# Obtain from file if present:
if [ -e $confFile ]; then
  echo "checking configuration file..."
  newport=$(grep server_port $confFile | awk -F= '{print $2}')
fi
echo "Switching to port $newport"

if [ ! -e ${httpd_conf}.orig ]; then
   sudo cp -p $httpd_conf ${httpd_conf}.orig
fi
sudo sed -i 's/Listen 80$/Listen 8080/' $httpd_conf
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [sed](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-basics-of-using-the-sed-stream-editor-to-manipulate-text-in-linux) for this:

For example if your ports.conf file looks like this:

```
Listen 80
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

to change the port to 8080 in a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo sed 's/80/8080/' /etc/apache2/ports.conf
sudo sed 's/80/8080/' /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf #for your examples sake
sudo service apache2 restart
```

HTH

Comment: This would replace 8080 by 808080. Also it would not change the file in place. Right would be `sed -i 's/Listen 80[[:space:]]*$/Listen 8080/' .../ports.conf .../sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

Comment: Need to add the -i flag to sed to change the file in place -  sudo sed -i 's/80/5000/' /etc/apache2/ports.conf